# What will happen when a laptop's hd graphic is dead?

Tags: laptop, gpu

I have an ultrabook laptop and I accidentally water damaged it, and had it repaired.

It worked fine for a few weeks, but now it won't boot with the HD Graphics enable even I reinstalled the HD Graphics driver. It stops at the windows booting logo.

I was able to boot into Safe Mode disabled the HD Graphics in Device Manager, and it booted OK.

I installed Debian and found that OS didn't detect the HD Graphics either.

This is my question:

How is my computer working without the HD Graphics enabled?

My laptop is Acer S7-391 i5 3337U, currently using debian 3.16.0-4-amd64, before the water damage it was running Windows 10. Now the video is very laggy, and the audio isn't synced with the video.

Comment: If the GPU within your i5 was dead then your laptop wouldn't function at all.

Comment: alot of computers don't have separate gpu's all those computers aren't ULTRABOOKs, ex. Fujitsu Lifebook

Comment: just a counter to what everyone else is saying. My experiance was with a dedicated GPU, so not sure how that compares, but anyway, when it's soilder partially melted (bad GPU design) I got the exact symptoms you are discribing, down to being able to boot without the driver enabled, and linux not seeing a gpu. So if the integrated graphics works the same way, you might indeed have dead hardware. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

A lack of GPU does not make your computer an Ultrabook.

An Ultrabook is a marketing term applied to computers with a particular size, shape, and weight, mostly.

When you got your laptop wet it may have damaged components inside the laptop. If the GPU itself is exhibiting unexpected/undesired behavior the damage is actually on your entire CPU die (the "chip") because that is where the GPU lives on your computer.

Based on your description of the symptoms, I'm guessing you're experiencing software issues not hardware. I may be wrong, but the delay between the damage and this issue and the nature of the issue seems to point in this direction.

What you should do is reinstall the operating system and get the latest drivers for your device. If things work OK at that point, then the issue was indeed just software. If you're still getting these issues with the integrated graphics not working, then the issue may indeed be hardware-related, and at that point it is likely that the cost to repair (replacing CPU and mainboard, at least) is higher than the actual value of the laptop.

Comment: Re-reading the question and seeing that you installed Debian AFTER the issues surfaced, I'm leaning more towards hardware BUT, drivers are generally a different beast on Linux, and unless you're certain you have the best drivers for Debian installed, I wouldn't consider this too much part of the symptoms. Restore your computer to Win10, update drivers, and see if the HD Graphics device works then.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will restore to windows 10, see if it is software of hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

You rare getting graphics on the display after booting into 'Safe Mode' because safe mode loads a very basic driver and does not enable your HD graphics whether on a gpu or MB.

Sometimes something can go wrong with particular circuits in hardware devices (ie: Capacitors and voltage regulators can start to fail or some circuit paths shorted or non-functioning.) and the hardware chip or circuit can partially work. If Loading the HD graphics driver did not solve your problem, then starting over with a fresh OS install can eliminate the possibility of software related issues but if Ubuntu could not find the graphic then I would surmise a guess that a fresh Windows install would produce similar results

TL:DR version. Sounds like some kind of hardware issue and those are difficult to track down on laptops.